# How do I make a 100% width fixed div to leave some space on right?

Tags: width, html, css-position

I have a `div` which has `position` set to `fixed`. This `div` is meant to be site's header.

The problem is that it should take `100 %` of the `width` **except** for leaving a small gap on the right edge, where we show a custom styled scroll-bar. The `body` of this page has been absolutely positioned and `overflow` set to `scroll` to present the custom scroll-bar.

I tried with `100%` width, but then it takes `100%` of the view-port instead of its parent. I also tried setting `margin-right` to scroll-bar width but it seems that is not honored. Is there a way to do this without using Javascript?

Comment: Welcome to the joys of css positioning/sizing, where nobody wins and the points don't matter.

Comment: provide some more materials (images, links, code), please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting width to 100% I would use something like

```
#header {
    height:30px; /* assumption */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:10px; /* assumption */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me just say this..

If your width is set to 100%, and you set margin-right: 20px;.. then the 20px is added to the original div.

Aside from that, I don't know what you're talking about without seeing it.